# Uninstall GlassFish Application Server

Tags: java, glassfish

How do you uninstall Glassfish Application Server?

I made a mistake in my installation and I want to change the directory of my Glassfish installation.

I just follow below sequence during installation.

1. Download the Glassfish V2 jar
2. Run below line java -Xmx256m -jar glassfish-installer-v2.1.1-b31g-windows.jar
3. Set the GLASSFISH_HOME variable

It says from the document that I saw from the net that there is an uninstall.exe option but I can seem to find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the contents of the directory to which glassfish was installed. You might also check for a file named .glassfish in your home directory, or something similar, and delete that as well.

I've worked with glassfish quite a bit and have never had problems removing it this way, though I can't say whether it is the 'official' way to do it.

Comment: @jk Thanks.  I was surprised how easy it is.  I do search for complicated internet link. LOL! =)

Comment: I would recommend using the "uninstall.sh" script, as strauberry said. Just deleting the files may work but the "right" way will be the provided uninstall script.

Comment: This falls on its ass if you've got a service running. If you can't remove the service, find it in Services, double-click it, get the service name from the top of the dialog and then, from an elevated command prompt do: `sc delete <ServiceName>` - Make sure you get the right service or you can bork your entire machine

Answer (score 5):

There's a uninstall.sh shell script in the glashfish-folder. Execute this with sudo, otherwise the files can not be deleted!

Answer (score 1):

Its a executable jar file and there are no register entries. So there is no need for an uninstall. Like the previous user had mentioned you just need to worry about any env variables pointing to obsolete glassfish location.

(Note: If you want to relocate just copy and paste to new folder).

Comment: JSS are you sure about this. I could be wrong, but if you look into asadmin the class path for the jar files are referenced as relative path. AS_INSTALL=`dirname "$0"`/../glassfish
AS_INSTALL_LIB="$AS_INSTALL/modules"
. "${AS_INSTALL}/config/asenv.conf"

Answer (score 1):

The GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 Installation Guide includes a section on uninstalling.  To uninstall a GlassFish that was installed using the JAR-based installer:

**Windows:** go the the Explorer window, choose the glassfish directory and delete all its contents.

**Solaris/UNIX:** run the following command:  rm -r glassfish.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0187/abnbk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

doc_180, 
just cut and poaste won't help becuase many files insite the bin directory are generated at installation time and they keep the directory path. And you will not be able to start the server.
So once directory has been moved to new location search for old directory entries and update them or delete the glassfish folder and start from scracth (later recommended).

Comment: Hi doc_180, Yes positive. I have got the following statement from my local glassfish asadmin.bat which was installed in the C:\Software directory. [call "C:\Software\Glassfish\config\asenv.bat"]

Answer (score 0):

These didn't work for me running java 1.6.0_24 in Windows 7:

- I tried modifying the asenv.bat file that glassfish uses to find the jre to point to my jre.
- I tried manually putting it in as in C:\glassfish3\uninstall.exe -j . This was per the official Oracle documentation.

The only thing that worked was to use the original path and move the bin and lib folders from my java installation to the directory that the error dialog specified. Then the Glassfish uninstall started up and completed with no problems.